# Postgresql Search for a value in jsonb object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in a table having values of the form

```
    {
  "message": {
    "sender": {
      "from": "91**********"
    },
    "channel": "some kind of text",
    "content": {
      "text": "some kind of text",
      "type": "text"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "to": "91**********",
      "recipient_type": "some kind of text"
    },
    "preferences": {
      "webHookDNId": "some kind of text"
    }
  },
  "metaData": {
    "version": "some kind of text"
  }
}
```

Now i want to search for all such value which in "to" key of the object has a certain phone number. i am using following query for this but it is not working

```
select * from table_name where (column1::jsonb ? '91**********') ;
```

Answer (score 4):

`?` looks for a top-level key.  The JSON you show only has two top-level keys, "message" and "metadata". So of course they don't match to '91**********'.

You probably want the containment operator `@>`:

```
 @> '{"message":{"recipient":{"to":"91**********"}}}'
```

This will be supported by the either type of JSONB GIN index on your column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `->` and `->>` [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to extract the value from a key:

```
select *
from the_table
where (the_column -> 'recipient' ->> 'to') = '91**********';
```

Or the `#>>` operator

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column #>> '{recipient,to}' = '91**********';
```